# When should a react component be declared as a function, and not a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm unsure of when to declare react components as simple standalone functions as opposed to the regular `class myComponent extends Component` syntax. To use an example from React's docs (located [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)):

The following is referred to as a "component"

```
function BoilingVerdict(props) {
  if (props.celsius >= 100) {
    return <p>The water would boil.</p>;
  }
  return <p>The water would not boil.</p>;
}
```

While it appears to merely be a function and is declared like any regular old function. Then in the next paragraph, the following is ALSO defined as a component, and looks more like the way I think a component should look:

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: ''};
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in Celsius:</legend>
        <input
          value={temperature}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(temperature)} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
```

What is the difference between these two "components"? Is the first example actually a component if it doesn't inherit from the Component class and isn't being created with `React.createClass`? I would appreciate somebody explaining this distinction since I couldn't find an answer anywhere in the docs.

Comment: The difference seems clear; one has state, one doesn't. The React docs state that functional ("function") components will have neither state nor lifecycle events (at least that include user code).

Answer (score 2):

When you don't need to use the [lifecycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) and the component isn't stateful you can declare the component as a function. Component lifecycle methods like `componentWillMount()` and `componentDidMount()` only can be used if the component is a class that extends `Component`.

Answer (score 1):

`Calculator` must be specified as a class-based component because it is dependent upon internal component state i.e. `this.setState({...})`. Functional components, also known as *stateless components* [do not have a *backing instance*](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4936#issuecomment-247749687), thus they are unable to maintain local state in the same way.

Personally, I always try to write functional components as they are arguably easier to test due to their nature of consuming props and returning a tree of `ReactElement` instances. I will only convert a component to be class-based if it will:

- need to manage its own presentation-based state i.e. not applicable to the state of the entire application
- benefit from lifecycle methods as a means of improving performance through restricted re-rendering
- require references to child `ReactElement`s or DOM nodes via [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are two complementary docs from Facebook that explain this quite well:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

TL;DR a "component" is primarily responsible for representing some DOM. Depending on how your application is organized, your component may or may not need to maintain its own state or have access to the lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount` or `render`. In the case that you do need these features, your component should be a class that inherits from `React.Component`. Otherwise, you can likely get away with writing your component as a plain old function.

Answer (score 0):

If the functional way is more preferred instead of creating classes you could use higher-order components utility called [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose), it has [lifecycle](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#lifecycle) HOC.

Small example:

```
const NewComponent = lifecycle({
      componentWillMount() {
        this.props.onEnterScreen();
      },
})(Component)
```

Comment: Noting that the recompose docs state this is more of an "escape hatch"; IMO if you have a component that will have lifecycle methods, you should just make a normal component rather than resorting to a HOC.